# How to concatenate all files in a directory using browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have a [directory](https://github.com/mentiflectax/browserify-question/tree/master/bpmn-viewer) with various JavaScript files. I want to create one big file out of them using browserify.

I tried `browserify bpmn-viewer/*.js --outfile browserify-output.js`, but got the following error:

```
Error: Parsing file /.../bpmn-viewer/moddle.js: Unexpected token (1:26)
    at Deps.parseDeps (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:519:15)
    at getDeps (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:447:44)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:430:38
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:37:43)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:214:15)
    at finishMaybe (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:630:14)
    at endWritable (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:638:3)
    at ConcatStream.Writable.end (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:594:41)
    at DuplexWrapper.onend (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:577:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:298:28)
```

How do I need to change my command (`browserify bpmn-viewer/*.js --outfile browserify-output.js`) in order to get the right result?

**Update 1:** After changing `moddle.js` to

```
module.exports=require(28);

var rts = require('./lib/moddle');

module.exports.types = require('./lib/types');

module.exports.ns = require('./lib/ns');
```

I am getting a different message:

```
Error: Parsing file browserify-question/bpmn-viewer/object-refs.js: Unexpected token (1:27)
    at Deps.parseDeps (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:519:15)
    at getDeps (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:447:44)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:430:38
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:37:43)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:214:15)
    at finishMaybe (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:630:14)
    at endWritable (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:638:3)
    at ConcatStream.Writable.end (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:594:41)
    at DuplexWrapper.onend (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:577:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:298:28)
```

The [object-refs.js](https://github.com/mentiflectax/browserify-question/blob/master/bpmn-viewer/object-refs.js) file looks like this:

```
module.exports=require(84)./lib/refs');

module.exports.Collection = require('./lib/collection');
```

**Update 2:** After modifying `object-refs.js` to

```
module.exports=require('./lib/refs');

module.exports.Collection = require('./lib/collection');
```

I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (22:0) while parsing /home/[...]/[...]/Development/Repositories/git/browserify-question/bpmn-viewer/jquery.js while parsing file: /home/[...]/[...]/Development/Repositories/git/browserify-question/bpmn-viewer/jquery.js
    at DestroyableTransform.end [as _flush] (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/insert-module-globals/index.js:114:21)
    at DestroyableTransform.prefinish (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:138:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at prefinish (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:619:14)
    at finishMaybe (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:627:5)
    at endWritable (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:638:3)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:594:41)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:577:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:298:28)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:214:15)
```

The problematic file is [jquery.js](https://github.com/mentiflectax/browserify-question/blob/master/bpmn-viewer/jquery.js). Based on the error message I think the error is somewhere on line 22.

Idea highlights a potential problem on line 19:

[image: Screenshot]

Here are the lines 1 through 22 of [jquery.js](https://github.com/mentiflectax/browserify-question/blob/master/bpmn-viewer/jquery.js):

```
module.exports=require('QRCzyp');if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
        // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper window is present,
        // execute the factory and get jQuery
        // For environments that do not inherently posses a window with a document
        // (such as Node.js), expose a jQuery-making factory as module.exports
        // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real window
        // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
        // See ticket #14549 for more info
        module.exports = global.document ?
            factory( global, true ) :
            function( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            };
    } else {
        factory( global );
    }

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
```

Comment: The exception mentions that there is an unexpected token. Do you see anything suspicious in your file moddle.js? (line one char 26)

Comment: @html_programmer Thanks for your comment. [Here](https://github.com/mentiflectax/browserify-question/blob/master/bpmn-viewer/moddle.js) is the contents of that file. The first line is `module.exports=require(28)rts = require('./lib/moddle');`. Will try to fix it a little later.

Comment: That looks suspicious. Although I'm not sure how this file was built, it complains about the rts declaration. Shouldn't it be something like `;var rts = ...`

Comment: @html_programmer I had a huge browserified file `bpmn-viewer.js`. Then I used unpackjs (`unpackjs bpmn-viewer.js`) to split it into multiple files for easier editing. Now I want to find out how I can combine the split-up files into the browserified version again.

Comment: I don't know that unpacking library, but if you try to add  `;var rts =` manually and try to run browserify again, I think it will continue past that point.

Comment: @html_programmer Did this. See *Update 1* in the question.

Comment: That import statement also seems to be a problem. Should probably be: `module.exports=require('./lib/refs');`. That generated code is fishy, you will probably have to work your way through solving all of the issues.

Comment: @html_programmer Thanks. I fixed the error in `object-refs`, got another one (see update 2). Regarding *generated code is fishy*: Imagine you have a big JS file, the results of browserify (multiple files concatenated to one). How can you "un-browserify" that file, i. e. split it into multiple files? I used `unpackjs bpmn-viewer.js` ([GitHub](https://github.com/Rob--W/unpackjs)), but if you know a better option, please tell.

Comment: Looks like this is part of a function declaration but the function signature seems to be missing. I don't think that there is a straightforward way to reverse the concatenation process, you would need the source code files. Doesn't look like this tool works too well...

Comment: @html_programmer If I wanted to split the file manually, how would I know where one file starts and ends? Do you know any tutorial on how to manually do what unpackjs did?